# Navigating an Array with Column Boundaries

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Let's say there is a square 2 dimensional array of N x N, represented as a one dimension array. Let the array be 5x5, like below, and the values in the array are not significant.

```
std::vector< int > array {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4
};
```

If we say that there are 5 rows and 5 columns in this array, how can one detect if they are on the edge of a row? For instance, if you are on the index of where 9 is on the 4th row, how can you know that you can go left without changing rows, but going right will advance to the next row? **How can one access a cell's neighbors with respect to edges? The index of where 9 is on the 4th row does not have a right neighbor.**

The only way I can think of how to do this would be the current index, in which case is

```
int index = row * num_cols + col
```

and perhaps use modulus (index % 5 == 0) to determine if on edge. But that does not determine if we can go left or right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
int row = index / N;
int col = index % N;
```

to get the row and column indices. For example, the 9th entry has row index 9/5=1 and column index 9%5=4.

Having computed the `(row, col)` coordinate, you can determine if it has the left or right neighbors. When `col == 0`, you don't have a left neighbor; when `col == N-1`, you don't have a right neighbor.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula

```
int index = row * num_cols + col;
```

Going up or down is equivalent to adding / subtracting `num_cols`.

is correct. The reverse of it is

```
int row = index / num_cols;
int col = index % num_cols;
```

You know you're on the left edge when `(index % num_cols) == 0`.

You know you're on the right edge when `(index % num_cols) == num_cols-1`.